# Python: df.mean seems to give the wrong output, why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-import, mean

**BACKGROUND:**
I am busy analysing data for various experimental work. The aim is to import an excel file with various sheets. Then "filter" the noise from the data and find the average of all the samples. Then plot a graph and save the graph.

**PROGRESS & PROBLEM:**
I have been able to do all the abovementioned steps, however, the final graph with the various samples vs the average thereof seems wrong to me. I am not sure whether the "df.mean" is the correct method of finding the average. I have attached the graph I get, somehow I can not agree that average can be so low?
[It can be seen that the saved image from my code cuts off the legend, how can I change this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgkKd.png)

**IMPROVEMENT NEEDED:**
This is my first question on stackoverflow and I am still new to Python. The code seems very "fluffy" and I would appreciate any suggestions on shortening the code.

**MY CODE:**

```
#IMPORT LIBRARIES
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#IMPORT DATA 
excel_df= pd.ExcelFile('data.xlsx',delimiter = ';') #import entire excel file
sheet1=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname=0,names=['time','void1','pressure1'])
sheet2=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname=1,names=['time','void2','pressure2'])
sheet3=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname=2,names=['time','void3','pressure3']) 
sheet4=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname=3,names=['time','void4','pressure4'])
sheet5=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname=4,names=['time','void5','pressure5'])
sheet6=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname=5,names=['time','void6','pressure6'])
sheet7=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname=6,names=['time','void7','pressure7'])
sheet8=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname=7,names=['time','void8','pressure8'])
sheet10=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname=9,names=['time','void10','pressure10'])

#SORT VALUES TO FIND THE UNWANTED DATA
sheet1.sort_values('pressure1',ascending=False).head() #the pressure has noise so sort accordingly

#GET ONLY WANTED DATA WITHOUT NOISE
sheet1_new = sheet1[sheet1.pressure1 <=8] #exclude the noise above 8 bar
sheet2_new = sheet2[sheet2.pressure2 <=8] #exclude the noise above 8 bar
sheet3_new= sheet3[sheet3.pressure3 <=8] #exclude the noise above 8 bar
sheet4_new = sheet4[sheet4.pressure4 <=8] #exclude the noise above 8 bar
sheet5_new = sheet5[sheet5.pressure5 <=8] #exclude the noise above 8 bar
sheet6_new = sheet6[sheet6.pressure6 <=8] #exclude the noise above 8 bar
sheet7_new = sheet7[sheet7.pressure7 <=8] #exclude the noise above 8 bar
sheet8_new = sheet8[sheet8.pressure8 <=8] #exclude the noise above 8 bar
sheet10_new = sheet10[sheet10.pressure10 <=8] #exclude the noise above 8 bar

#MERGE THE DATASETS TO FIND AVERAGE OF ALL SAMPLES

#'MERGE' ONLY MERGES 2 DATAFRAMES AT A TIME
merge12_df = pd.merge(sheet1_new,sheet2_new, on='time')
merge34_df = pd.merge(sheet3_new,sheet4_new, on='time')
merge56_df = pd.merge(sheet5_new,sheet6_new, on='time')
merge78_df = pd.merge(sheet7_new,sheet8_new, on='time')

#MERGE ON FIRST OUTPUT
all_merged = merge12_df.merge(merge34_df, on='time').merge(merge56_df, on = 'time').merge(merge78_df, on = 'time').merge(sheet10_new, on = 'time')
#print(all_merged.head()) #check that all data is merged into one dataframe

#AVERAGE ALL PRESSURES
mean_all_pressures = all_merged[["pressure1", "pressure2","pressure3", "pressure4","pressure5", "pressure6","pressure7", "pressure8", "pressure10"]].mean(axis=1)

#PRINT AVERAGE VS ALL THE SAMPLES GRAPH 
plt.figure(1) 
plt.plot(all_merged.time,mean_all_pressures,'r.') #plot the average of all samples.
plt.plot(sheet1_new.time,sheet1_new.pressure1)
plt.plot(sheet2_new.time,sheet2_new.pressure2)
plt.plot(sheet3_new.time,sheet3_new.pressure3)
plt.plot(sheet4_new.time,sheet4_new.pressure4)
plt.plot(sheet5_new.time,sheet5_new.pressure5)
plt.plot(sheet6_new.time,sheet6_new.pressure6)
plt.plot(sheet7_new.time,sheet7_new.pressure7)
plt.plot(sheet8_new.time,sheet8_new.pressure8)
plt.plot(sheet10_new.time,sheet10_new.pressure10)
plt.legend(['Average','Sample 1','Sample 2','Sample 3','Sample 4','Sample 5','Sample 6','Sample 7','Sample 8','Sample 10'],bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)'),plt.ylabel('Pressure (bar)') #Specify the plot details
plt.savefig('AllPressures_vs_Average.png') #Save the plot for later use
plt.show() #Display the plot
```

Comment: `for num in range(1,11):` could save a lot of code here...

Comment: The average is the red dots on the graph. My first image did not upload correctly.

Comment: sanity check the mean value by explicitly doing the calculation yourself i.e. summing over the filtered pressure values & dividing but the sample number.

Comment: What makes you think the mean is wrong?  It looks fine at first glance.  Have you tried printing out the values and checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the repetition in your code comes from the fact that you define a separate variable for each sheet and then do the same operation on each of them.

You can improve your current code by storing the content of each sheet into a single dictionary, rather than separate variables.

From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), you see that by specifying s`heetname = None`, you can import all sheets as a dictionary. Or alternatively you can provide the list of sheets you want to read, in your case `[0,1,2,...,11]` as they are 0-indexed.

```
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname=None,names=['time','void1','pressure1'])
```

You can quickly see what you have using:

```
for name, sheet in sheets_dict.iteritems():
    print name, sheet.head()
```

You can access each sheet individually when you need:

```
sheets_dict['sheet_1_name']
```

And this would avoid a lot of repetition.
For example, the filtering would simply be:

```
new_sheets_dict = {key: el[el.pressure1 <=8] for key, el in sheets_dict.iteritems)}
```